# How to solve for x for a built-in function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I'am traying to solve for p for a binomial distribution function where p is the probability of success.

I have tried many methods but none of them worked, shown bellow one of the methods that I have used:

```
syms p

y = 1 - binocdf(5,15,p) == 0.999;

X = vpasolve(y, p,[-1 1]);
```

This is the error that I got after running the code:

> Error using symengine Unable to prove 'p < 0 | 1 < p' literally. Use
>   'isAlways' to test the statement mathematically. Error in
>   sym/subsindex (line 792)
>                   X = find(mupadmex('symobj::logical',A.s,9)) - 1;
>
> Error in sym/privsubsasgn (line 1067)
>                   L_tilde2 = builtin('subsasgn',L_tilde,struct('type','()','subs',{varargin}),R_tilde);
>
> Error in sym/subsasgn (line 904)
>               C = privsubsasgn(L,R,inds{:});
>
> Error in binocdf (line 63) y(k1) = NaN;
>
> Error in myfun (line 6) y=binocdf(5,15,p)==0.999;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ***function handle*** instead  of ***syms function*** as `binocdf()` doesn't allow `p` to be ***syms*** variable

```
y = 1 - binocdf(5,15,p) == 0.999;
```

could be rewritten as

```
y = 1 - binocdf(5,15,p) - 0.999 == 0;
```

- Using ***function handle***, omitting the ***right hand side*** of
  the equation

```
y = @(p)1 - binocdf(5,15,p) - 0.999
```

`fzero()` finds the root of a function, in another words solves the equation `y == 0`

Also the third parameter in `binocdf(5,15,p)`, namely `p` is a ***probability*** ranging from `0` to `1`

- change the range from `[-1, 1]` to `[0, 1]`

```
fzero(y, [0 1])
```

---

**The entire code is as follows**

```
y = @(p)1 - binocdf(5,15,p) - 0.999;
X = fzero(y, [0 1])
```

**Result**

```
X = 0.7432
```